# how to access a specific value of a key within a Perl structure?

Tags: perl, geocoding

Assume this structure of a `Geo::Coder::Google` data dump --- `dd $location;`.

```
  address_components => [
    {
      long_name => "Blackheath Avenue",
      short_name => "Blackheath Ave",
      types => ["route"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "Greater London",
      short_name => "Gt Lon",
      types => ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "United Kingdom",
      short_name => "GB",
      types => ["country", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      short_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      types => ["postal_code"],
    },
    { long_name => "London", short_name => "London", types => ["postal_town"] },
  ],
  formatted_address => "Blackheath Avenue, London SE10 8XJ, UK",
  geometry => {
    bounds        => {
      northeast => { lat => 51.4770228, lng => 0.0005404 },
      southwest => { lat => 51.4762273, lng => -0.0001147 },
    },
    location      => { lat => 51.4766277, lng => 0.0002212 },
    location_type => "APPROXIMATE",
    viewport      => {
      northeast => { lat => 51.4779740302915, lng => 0.00156183029150203 },
      southwest => { lat => 51.4752760697085, lng => -0.00113613029150203 },
    },
  },
  types => ["route"],
}
```

An example call:

```
my $long_name = &get_field_for_location("long_name", $location);
```

Following sub returns the first `long_name` (in this example --- type=route):

```
sub get_field_for_location($$) {
  my $field    = shift;
  my $location = shift;

  my $address = $location->{address_components};
  return $_->{$field} for @$address;
}
```

How to access a `long_name` of another type? i.e. how to modify this sub to access a `$field` for a given type entry?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: it was not my intention to get only the first entry. for saving time, i asked how to cope with this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should return first of type `political`,

```
my $type = "political";

my ($first_of_type) =  grep { 
  grep { $_ eq $type } @{$_->{types}}; 
} @$address;

return $first_of_type->{$field};
```

Outer `grep` filters elements of `@$address` array, and inner `grep` filters elements of `types`, ie. `["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]`

Answer (score 3):

`types` is a reference to an array of strings. You will need to check if any of them matches the required type. You can do this using [`List::Util::first`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html):

```
use List::Util qw(first);

sub get_field_for_location {
    my $field = shift;
    my $location = shift;
    my $type = shift;

    my $address = $location->{'address_components'};
    for my $component (@{$address}) {
        if (first { $_ eq $type } @{$component->{'types'}}) {
            return $component->{$field};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1  it works when adding   my $address = $location->{address_components}; --- sorry - can mark only 1 answer