# How to use a Perl structure with generic subs?

Tags: perl, geocoding

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570737/how-to-access-a-specific-value-of-a-key-within-a-perl-structure), a concrete example is given how to access a specific key.
Anyway, is there best practice known when coding a sub that an arbitrary key can be accessed? For instance, `sub get_lat` would be a concrete attribute-Latitude. But focus on a more general option such as `sub get_value_by_keys($$$)`. `&get_value_by_keys(bounds,northeast,lat)` would return `51.4770228`.

```
  address_components => [
    {
      long_name => "Blackheath Avenue",
      short_name => "Blackheath Ave",
      types => ["route"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "Greater London",
      short_name => "Gt Lon",
      types => ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "United Kingdom",
      short_name => "GB",
      types => ["country", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      short_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      types => ["postal_code"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "London", short_name => "London", types => ["postal_town"]
    },
  ],

  formatted_address => "Blackheath Avenue, London SE10 8XJ, UK",   
  geometry => {
    bounds        => {
      northeast => { lat => 51.4770228, lng => 0.0005404 },
      southwest => { lat => 51.4762273, lng => -0.0001147 },
    },
    location      => { lat => 51.4766277, lng => 0.0002212 },
    location_type => "APPROXIMATE",
    viewport      => {
      northeast => { lat => 51.4779740302915, lng => 0.00156183029150203 },
      southwest => { lat => 51.4752760697085, lng => -0.00113613029150203 },
    },
  },

  types => ["route"],

}
```

Any hints how to resolve this issue and how to cope with a structure like that?

Comment: Your data structure has an excess closing brace and isn't valid Perl. Please post something that will compile.

Comment: that was the data dump output from an old syslog aka a return value of Data::Dumper as far as i remember concerning a location returned by a geocoder. that sould not be compiled cause it's not a code.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` generates valid, compileable Perl code. But the sample you have posted has been truncated so that it is no longer valid. Please post the whole of it.

Comment: the syslog was not retained over the long term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To descend into an arbitrary level of a data structure, start at the top. Use a variable to hold the reference to the current level and update it each time you find the next level. If you make it all the way to the end, that's the value you wanted:

```
sub get_value_by_keys {
    my( $current_level, @keys ) = @_;

    foreach my $key ( @keys ) {
        if( eval{ exists $current_level->{$key} } ) {
            print "$key key exists\n";
            $current_level = $current_level->{$key}; # the trick
            }
        else { return }
        }

    return $current_level;
    }
```

Then, call it with the data structure and keys that you want:

```
get_value_by_keys( $data, qw( geometry bounds northeast lat) );
```

You don't need the prototypes at all.

Comment: that's really awesome

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of CPAN modules doing what you want. For example `Data::Diver`:

```
use Data::Diver qw(Dive);
print Dive($data, qw(geometry bounds northeast lat)), "\n";
```

Advantage of this module is that it can deal also with array references within the data structure. For example, to get the long_name of the 2nd address component use:

```
print Dive($data, qw(address_components 1 long_name)), "\n";
```

Other modules implement a XPath-similar syntax (`Data::DPath`, `Data::Path`), here you would use a string like `"//geometry/bounds/northeast/lat"` to access values.

Comment: sorry - have already implemented the other version which works fine. your answer will be tested/used maybe another time. but thanks a lot.